# Prevent java from outputting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to stderr

Tags: java, stderr

When my environment variable define a non-empty value for JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, the jvm prints its content to standard error, which breaks some build tools relying on emptiness of stderr to tell if a build succeeded or not.
This can be tried by writing a very simple hello world class and run:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfoo=bar" java HelloWorld > /dev/null
```

You will normally see an output which is not really an error so I don't understand why it apperas in stderr. So there is maybe a way to disable this behavior but I couldn't find anything.

I am using the 1.7.0_45 jre.

Comment: According to the Q&A I linked to, the answer is that you can't disable the message.